# how to create public key to 34 max lenght characters using node js and crypto js

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

```js
function generateKeyPair() {
    if (fs.existsSync('privateKey.pem' || 'publicKey.pem')) {
        console.log("You already have keys, move your keys if you want generate new Wallet (publicKey.pem & privateKey.pem)")
    } else {
        const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'spki', format: 'pem' },
            privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'pem' }
        })

        fs.writeFile('privateKey.pem', privateKey, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err
        })

        fs.writeFile('publicKey.pem', publicKey, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err
        })

        console.log('Private key : ' + privateKey)
        console.log('\nPublic key : ' + publicKey)
        console.log("Yours keys has been generated into the main folder. (privateKey.pem & publicKey.pem)")
    }
}
generateKeyPair()
```

this code gives me a public key like this one

```js
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA3ocpUvL9gnAHkbLY1zlu
0qIOa9S/D1O5yK+Hj6ttiaFSsyU/5ca6JSVb3BYetf4vS0Fn7IYxfoxTjuJAg/K/
MDGzr0WUQaFTXcRbvGQhxAjdmzrW8zjkBHuEGHA1C3x5f1uqqD20mRZQgp6yEg6e
TIDWXWdmEWajVbVNEoYRra9DYPJqfXGGeNgWgXmM+wvbc30+5tx7emKCiRQuMaFX
rXvuH0DQMzGQVyejqSOaYvFue8GAlIn00vG+r2GuII8Ex0Feya/DZM1wbQ5iZunC
cBmm8Cc9M0x/ZyIwiR+EwncnPjxjig2E/Oi8Px13czxUESWX80+PcI1OgFETUTQm
kwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I would like a shorter key between 34 and 50 max length, I don't know which format could I use
to get to this size.

Comment: That is a formatted public key, the formatting adheres to a standard and, as a result, the key in this format is portable to many different applications. In any event, no RSA secure RSA public key can be anywhere near as short as 50 characters. It's possible to base-64 encode the x-coordinate of an elliptic curve public key over a 256-bit field in as few as 43 characters. It won't be in SPKI PEM format however.

Comment: which format should I use to get your 43 characters ? @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Comment: It's not a format at all, it's just the base x-coordinate in bytes that's then base-64 encoded.

Comment: do you know a library available to create a pair, make a signature and verify the signature? @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll answer my own question.

In fact you don't need to use RSA cryptography keys which generate more complex and longer keys.

There is another way to achieve your goals, you just need to use the elliptic and js-sha3 libraries to generate an ECDSA key pair.

Your ECDSA key will be in hex format, so then you convert your public key to BASE58 and you'll get a 44 character key, which isn't bad.

RSA and ECDSA keys provide equivalent security, so don't worry.